# count method in Java

Tags: java, methods, count

How is this method is a count method? can someone please help me understand it, especially, what is the role of int a? Thanks

```
private static int _______ (int[] values, int a) {
    int k = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while (k < values.length) {
        if (values[k] == a) {
            n++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6kmi.png)

Comment: a seems to be the value to count occurence into the array

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted?

Comment: My guess is because it seems very low effort and is asking to understand a very, very basic snippet of code.

Comment: I see why my question getting downvoted.  It may be very very basic for other people, but it may not be very very basic for me.  But yes, I will try to put more effort, think hard and careful before I asked a question. :)

Answer (score 6):

The method counts the number of values in the array that match `a`. `k` is the loop counter. It's used to access each value in the `values` array. Each of those values is compared to `a`, and if a match is found the counter `n` is incremented.

Answer (score -1):

This method count the occurrences of valueToCompare in values.
That should be:

```
private static int countMatches(int[] values, int valueToCompare) {
int k = 0;
int numberOfMatches= 0;
while (k < values.length) {
    if (values[k] == valueToCompare) {
        numberOfMatches++;
    }
    k++;
}
return numberOfMatches;
```